# URL amigável com parâmetros no HTACCESS

Tags: php, htaccess

estou passando o site antigo todo para url amigavel e com isso veio varios problemas no site antigo a url era dessa maneira

http://meusite/download/programa.php?title=avast-free-antivirus

e com a nova url queria que ficasse dessa maneira

http://meusite/download/avast-free-antivirus

ai entrei no HTACCESS e criei essas regras

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^/download/([a-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /download/programa.php?title=$1 [NC]
```

então ao acessar http://meusite/download/avast-free-antivirus para o servidor vou esta acessando a pagina http://meusite/download/programa.php?title=avast-free-antivirus

e na pagina programa faço a verificacao se o que esta vindo na variavel title e igual a algum titulo do banco de dados

so que dessa forma a url não funciona não sei se é porque fiz alguma coisa erra ou se nao pode fazer dessa maneira 
ao acessar http://meusite/download/avast-free-antivirus da o erro 
Not Found

Not Found

The requested URL /download/avast-free-antivirus was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/5.6.25 Server at mega Port 80

diz que a pagina nao foi encontrada

Comment: Tente corrigir isso: ([a-z0-9\-]+), o hífen é um caracter, se vc não colocar a barra invertida, talvez esteja dando erro, e não permitindo uso de hífen.

Answer (score 2):

Você fez isso:

```
RewriteRule ^/download/([a-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /download/programa.php?title=$1 [NC]
```

Mas pelo que parece desejar o correto é isto (e remova o `/` da frente de ambos `download/`):

```
RewriteRule ^download/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ download/programa.php?title=$1 [NC]
```

Comment: sim eu esqueci de tirar isso era do segundo parametro da url programa.php?title=$&id=$2 mais o certo e como voce falouRewriteRule ^/download/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ /download/programa.php?title=$1 [NC] mais mesmo assim da o erro nao sei o que esta errado

Comment: @diogoDsa acho que descobri, faça isto: `RewriteRule ^download/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ download/programa.php?title=$1 [NC]` (veja que troquei `/download/` por `download/`)

Comment: agora funcionou tudo certo brigado pela ajuda

Comment: Se a resposta resolveu teu problema marque-a como correta por favor, se não sabe como fazer leia: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/3635